# Server 2012 Hyper-V: use lan AND wlan for client?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, switch, virtualization

Short version: I am trying to use my notebook as a Windows server 2012 Hyper-V enviroment, which is working quiet well. But I have this question: Is it possible (maybe via virtual switch configuration?) to define ONE network switch for a client system, that can use a lan or/and a wlan connection, depending how I connect to the internet?

I want to access the internet with my client system, whether I am at the office (where I use a LAN connection) or I am at home (where I use a WLAN connection) ...

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Configure two network adapters on your VM (called a *guest*, not a "client," FWIW) - one wireless, one wired.  Pass them through to your physical wired and wireless adapters.  (Called bridged-mode networking in the VMWare world, not sure if it's the same term with Hyper-V or not.)

When you have a wired connection, your VM will be able to connect through it, when you're associated to a wireless network, your VM will be able to use it.

Comment: Sometimes life/computer/work/universe can be SO easy! Will try it tomorrow morning, because it doesn't work right now ... and it's 1:47 AM here :-) THANK YOU!

Comment: UPDATE: it works! I have to add a "legacy network adapter" (not only a "network adapter"). Thank you again! Greetings from a happy hyper-v user from germany :-)